# ¿Cómo utilizar paginación en bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Estoy obteniendo información desde una Api y no tengo ni idea de como paginar la información, lo que muestro por pantalla son simplemente titulos de artículos que dinámicamente con Jquery los voy insertando en etiquetas h4, por lo que me sale en la pantalla unos 40 titulos, lo que quiero es paginarlo y que salgan por ejemplo 5 artículos por página, pero no tengo ni idea de utilizar la paginación. me faltan los conceptos, ahora mismo tengo todo en un index.html

código html:

```
<body>
<!-- <div class="app"> -->
<div class="container-fluid">    
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="articulos">

            </div>    
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </div>





</div>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();


    $.getJSON('https://www.llamadaapi.json', function(data) {
      var articulos = data['articles'];

        //titulo = $('h2');


        var j = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < articulos.length; i++) {
            if (articulos[i]['lang'] == 'es') {
                $('.articulos').append("<h4/>");
                //$(titulo[j]).text(articulos[i]['title']);
                j++;    
            }
        }

        j = 0;
        titulo = $('h4');
        for (var i = 0; i < articulos.length; i++) {
            if (articulos[i]['lang'] == 'es') {

                $(titulo[j]).text(articulos[i]['title']);
                j++;
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Ejemplo de la salida en chrome:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje lo quieres?

Comment: Estás usando correctamente __los estilos de paginacion__ de Bootstrap, por lo que no está ahí el problema (deberías cambiar tu título). Tu servidor debería crear los datos paginados para que tu frontend los consuma más fácilmente. Debes indicar que lenguaje usas.

Comment: lo quiero paginar con Jquery, o con algun plugin de Jquery, lo que tengo en mi página index son un monton de <h4> con el titulo de cada articulo, esos h4 que previamente he sacado de un json es lo que quiero paginar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si es en jQuery, utiliza este ejemplo http://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/paginacion-jquery-ajax-php/ es muy sencillo, en este caso lo haces solo con la etiqueta `<h4>`, te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
    <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.paginate').live('click', function(){

        $('#content').html('<div><img src="images/loading.gif" width="70px" height="70px"/></div>');

        var page = $(this).attr('data');        
        var dataString = 'page='+page;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/pagination.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#content').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            }
        });
    });              
});    
</script>
```

En el controlador debes hacer llegar la información que querrás mostrar y dividir-la, te quedará algo así:

```
<?php

require('config.php');

$query_num_services =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM services WHERE status=1", $conexion);
$num_total_registros = mysql_num_rows($query_num_services);

//Si hay registros
 if ($num_total_registros > 0) {
    //numero de registros por página
    $rowsPerPage = 3;

    //por defecto mostramos la página 1
    $pageNum = 1;

    // si $_GET['page'] esta definido, usamos este número de página
    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        sleep(1);
        $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
    }

    //contando el desplazamiento
    $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
    $total_paginas = ceil($num_total_registros / $rowsPerPage);

    $query_services = mysql_query("SELECT service_id, title, description, rating FROM services WHERE status=1 ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage", $conexion);
    while ($row_services = mysql_fetch_array($query_services)) {
       //Mostramos los sevicios
       ...
    }
...
?>
```

Luego mostrarías el html mediante **echo's** :

```
if ($total_paginas > 1) {
    echo '<div class="paginate">';
    echo '<ul>';
    if ($pageNum != 1)
        echo '<li><a data="'.($pageNum-1).'">Anterior</a></li>';
        for ($i=1;$i<=$total_paginas;$i++) {
            if ($pageNum == $i)
                //si muestro el índice de la página actual, no coloco enlace
                echo '<li><a>'.$i.'</a></li>';
            else
                //si el índice no corresponde con la página mostrada actualmente,
                //coloco el enlace para ir a esa página
                echo '<li><a data="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
         }
         if ($pageNum != $total_paginas)
             echo '<li><a data="'.($pageNum+1).'">Siguiente</a></li>';
         echo '</ul>';
          echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Y finalmente, dónde quieras que aparezca la información en tu página:

```
<div id="central">
   <div class="title">Artículos</div>
   <div id="content"><?php require('includes/pagination.php'); ?></div>    
</div>
```

Todo lo tienes muy bien explicado en esta web también, cualquier duda, comenta :)

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[html5](/questions/tagged/html5)[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido bastante para mi código.

Comment: :) me alegro, cualquier otra duda ya sabes stackoverflow